# Как задать новые bitmap options к старому bitmap?

Tags: android

У меня есть картинка я ее конвертирую в битмап

```
Bitmap in = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mC.getResources(), iRes);
```

Теперь я проверяю высоту и если она превышает высоту моего экрана больше чем в 2 раза то мне нужно пременить к ней вот такое

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();         
options.inSampleSize = scale;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mC.getResources(), iRes, options);
```

Проблема в том, что я создаю обьект битмап делаю проверку по высоте и если `true` то создаю битмап заново с учетом `downscale`

Но я хочу узнать как можно не создавать обьект заново, а применить `options` к уже имеющемуся обьекту

Comment: Есть такой метод [`Bitmap.reconfigure(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#reconfigure(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)), **но** доступен с `API19` и размер выделенной под битмап памяти не меняется - новая конфигурация **должна** укладываться в тот же размер. Так же расход памяти и не уменьшается в новом конфиге - если это критично. Есть там ещё пара вариантов, но с таким же подходом к использованию памяти и повторным декодированием ресурса.

Comment: @woesss мне подходит если он с 19 апи. Можете опубликовать пример кода?